# What is the "buffer size" (audio) and how to choose the best amount of buffer size?

Tags: sound, jack

I'm learning about jack. There's something called the "buffer size" and is measured in samples. What is it and how to choose a good buffer size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **JACK Properties**
>
> Sample Rate, Buffer Size and Periods/Buffer determine the base JACK
>   latency. Their default values of 48000, **1024** and 2 respectively should
>   work with most devices but a latency over 10ms is not usually
>   considered good enough to be called realtime. Anyone interested in
>   multitrack recording may wish to experiment with these settings to
>   achieve the lowest, xrun-free latency their hardware will allow. It is
>   possible to achieve 1ms latency with good hardware and the correct
>   configuration.

A smaller buffer gives lower latency. The lowest size most devices can handle is **64** but lower quality hardware may not handle any lower than **512**.

For instance a smaller value like **128** for buffer size will help reduce latency if you will be recording non-midi instruments.

Sources:

- [How To Configure Jack and Ardour in Ubuntu Linux for Recording Midi](http://sungwonchoe.com/how-to-configure-jack-and-ardour-in-ubuntu-linux-for-recording-midi/)
- [JACK configuration](http://kxstudio.sourceforge.net/Documentation:Manual:jack_configuration)